# Dynamically Lookup Value with Between - Excel

Tags: excel-formula, lookup

I have a chronological list of Product, Year, Month, Profit (like below).

**Summary Table**

```
Product Year    Month   Profit
TV      2018    1       10
TV      2018    2       20
TV      2018    3       30
TV      2018    4       50
TV      2018    5       35
TV      2018    6       60
TV      2018    7       90
Heater  2018    1       20
Heater  2018    2       3
Heater  2018    3       8
Heater  2018    4       4
Heater  2018    5       6
Heater  2018    6       11
Heater  2018    7       1
```

What I wanted to do is lookup another sheet that has all of the price changes within by month and year as well as the table below shows.

**Sale Price**

```
Product Year    Month   Price
TV      2018    1       $1,000.00
TV      2018    4       $800.00
TV      2018    7       $950.00
Heater  2018    1       $20.00
Heater  2018    2       $60.00
Heater  2018    5       $45.00
```

So the end result for example, TV Month = 2 and Year = 2018, I want it to pull in $1,000 to be part of my profit calculation.

Comment: so your output would be what and where would it go?

Comment: @ScottCraner The output will be used for my profit calculation Where if my profit = Sales Price - SUM(operating cost + product cost + employee cost)

Comment: So you want the price to show up in a new column next to the profit column in the first table?

Comment: @ScottCraner I want to pull it into my profit equation, where the other 3 costs are static, but sales price is the only variable that can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the correct Price, use:

```
=INDEX(J:J,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($I$2:$I$7)/(($G$2:$G$7=A2)*($H$2:$H$7=B2)*($I$2:$I$7<=C2)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: then please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I was trying to transfer my excel sheet to Google sheet but they do not have the aggregate function, would you know if there is an alternative to aggregate?

Comment: @Kevin that is a new question but look into the arrayformula(large(if()))