# Aggregate equivalent in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to upload an excel sheet to Google Sheet but they do not have an Aggregate function that I used. The link below is the question I originally asked, would someone have a way to convert this to Google Sheet?

Original Question : [Dynamically Lookup Value with Between - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199851/dynamically-lookup-value-with-between-excel/51200004?noredirect=1#comment89404355_51200004)

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this in Google Sheets

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,sort({Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B&Sheet2!C2:C,Sheet2!D2:D},1,true),2,true))
```

If you place it in E2 of Sheet1 it should expand downwards.